# How to align list items in vim

Tags: vim, text-alignment

Say I have PHP code which looks like this

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'longfoo' => 'otherbar',
    'baz' => 'foobar,
);
```

Is there a way in Vim to align the array values and format it like following?

```
$values = array(
    'foo'       => 'bar',
    'longfoo'   => 'otherbar',
    'baz'       => 'foobar,
);
```

Minor note: I use spaces, not tabs for indenting.

Comment: know that doing that leads to reformatting arrays when you add/delete keys leading to pointless whitespace diffs in commits (assuming you're using a vcs).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Still i think the improved readability is worth this price.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin would make that easy.  After installing that you could 
simply run

```
:Tabularize /=>/
```

while on any of the lines which are to be 
aligned. If you use that same pattern often, you could even setup a mapping to 
do that even faster.

Comment: Neat, thanks. Do you also happen know if there's a way to make tabular align the text on tabstops? E.g. if have `tabstop` set to 4, how can i make the `=>` to be align on one of the columns 4, 8, 12, 16, ... etc?

Answer (score 7):

Tabularize sounds like the way to go, but I will also mention the Unix utility `column`, which is pretty nifty and more people should know about.
Unix-specific, obviously. (On openSuSE 12.3, it's in the util-linux package; likely different on other distributions.)
To invoke it within vim, visually select the lines you want to align, then
`:!column -t`
So with the visual range that vim fills in for you when you hit `:` with lines selected, you get:
 `:'<,'>!column -t`
(By default it separates on whitespace, but you can change that with the `-s <separator>` option.)
It aligns things such that each column is just long enough for its longest member.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the plugin [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294). It has some very handy shortcuts, like `\tsp` could let you align columns by spaces quickly.